# How to orbit view control in ignition

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I can't figure out how to rotate the view in ignition.  This may be due to being on a laptop without a proper mouse, but I haven't found the magic combination to rotate the display.  The combinations I've tried of left/right mouse button with shift, ctrl, and alt don't seem to work.

Do I need to load a special plugin/setting for this?

My sdf:

```
<sdf version="1.7">
  <world name="inertia">
    <gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
    <magnetic_field>6e-06 2.3e-05 -4.2e-05</magnetic_field>
    <atmosphere type="adiabatic"/>
    <physics name="1ms" type="ignored">
      <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
      <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
      <real_time_update_rate>1000</real_time_update_rate>
    </physics>
    <scene>
      <ambient>0.4 0.4 0.4 1</ambient>
      <background>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</background>
      <shadows>1</shadows>
    </scene>
    <plugin filename="libignition-gazebo-physics-system.so" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Physics"/>
    <plugin filename="libignition-gazebo-user-commands-system.so" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::UserCommands"/>
    <plugin filename="libignition-gazebo-scene-broadcaster-system.so" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::SceneBroadcaster"/>
    <gui fullscreen="0">
      <plugin filename="GzScene3D" name="3D View">
        <ignition-gui>
          <title>3D View</title>
          <property key="showTitleBar" type="bool">0</property>
          <property key="resizable" type="bool">0</property>
          <property key="z" type="double">0</property>
          <anchor line="right" target="window" target_line="right"/>
          <anchor line="left" target="window" target_line="left"/>
          <anchor line="top" target="window" target_line="top"/>
          <anchor line="bottom" target="window" target_line="bottom"/>
        </ignition-gui>
        <engine>ogre</engine>
        <scene>scene</scene>
        <ambient_light>0.4 0.4 0.4</ambient_light>
        <background_color>0.8 0.8 0.8</background_color>
        <camera_pose>-6 0 6 0 0.5 0</camera_pose>
      </plugin>
      <plugin filename="WorldControl" name="World control">
        <ignition-gui>
          <title>World control</title>
          <property key="showTitleBar" type="bool">0</property>
          <property key="resizable" type="bool">0</property>
          <property key="height" type="double">72</property>
          <property key="width" type="double">121</property>
          <property key="z" type="double">1</property>
          <anchor line="left" target="window" target_line="left"/>
          <anchor line="bottom" target="window" target_line="bottom"/>
        </ignition-gui>
        <play_pause>1</play_pause>
        <step>1</step>
        <start_paused>1</start_paused>
        <service>/world/inertia/control</service>
        <stats_topic>/world/inertia/stats</stats_topic>
      </plugin>
      <plugin filename="WorldStats" name="World stats">
        <ignition-gui>
          <title>World stats</title>
          <property key="showTitleBar" type="bool">0</property>
          <property key="resizable" type="bool">0</property>
          <property key="height" type="double">110</property>
          <property key="width" type="double">290</property>
          <property key="z" type="double">1</property>
          <anchor line="right" target="window" target_line="right"/>
          <anchor line="bottom" target="window" target_line="bottom"/>
        </ignition-gui>
        <sim_time>1</sim_time>
        <real_time>1</real_time>
        <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
        <iterations>1</iterations>
        <topic>/world/inertia/stats</topic>
      </plugin>
      <plugin filename="EntityTree" name="Entity tree">
        <ignition-gui>
          <title>Entity tree</title>
        </ignition-gui>
      </plugin>
      <plugin filename="ComponentInspector" name="Component inspector"/>
    </gui>
    <light name="sun" type="directional">
      <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
      <pose>0 0 10 0 -0 0</pose>
      <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
      <specular>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</specular>
      <attenuation>
        <range>1000</range>
        <constant>0.9</constant>
        <linear>0.01</linear>
        <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
      </attenuation>
      <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
      <spot>
        <inner_angle>0</inner_angle>
        <outer_angle>0</outer_angle>
        <falloff>0</falloff>
      </spot>
    </light>
    <model name="ground_plane">
      <static>1</static>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <link name="link">
        <collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>1 1</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <friction>
              <ode/>
            </friction>
            <contact/>
          </surface>
        </collision>
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <ambient>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</ambient>
            <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
            <specular>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</specular>
          </material>
        </visual>
      </link>
    </model>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25450/how-to-orbit-view-control-in-ignition/) by [athackston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28658/athackston/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The only way to orbit on Ignition right now is with the mouse's center button. I just ticketed an issue, it shouldn't be too hard to add Shift + drag like we have on Gazebo-classic: https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign-gazebo/issues/232

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0